# Jasper Reports, pass a list/array within a bean

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have to generate a report, that displays info about one object ( so the input is only one bean ).

The first problem is - this bean should contain **lists** of sub-beans( for example, comments, with comment type and comment date ). So I can pass them to a sub-report.

The second problem is - there is an **array** of 4 sub-beans, that contains few fields. I can create a separate field for each sub-bean's property ( firstSubBeanName, secondSubBeanName... ) , but it's ugly :(. Ideally, there should be a way to access these beans in a such way :

```
$F{test}[0].name
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work, provided that the field is declared with the appropriate type (i.e. com.foo.bar.SomeBean[]). Have you tried it? Do you have any error?

Comment: Well, I didn't know how to specify the type 'array of something', at least with generics it doesn't work. But it works well with lists, so the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list have a name (ie is a property of the object), you have just to pass as Data Source Expression for the subreport this property

```
$F{subBeansList}
```

The subreport should be ready to receive such kind of data. If you are using struts, it is possible you should use this class:

```
org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.ValueStackDataSource
```

as intermediary on your list field to be passed to the subreport.

The second question, the easy way is to use a list, so you can use this expression:

```
$F{test}.thelist.get(0)
```